# Ограничение максимального времени на стороне SQL

Tags: sql

Выполняю тестовое задание "система голосований за рестораны", где один из подпунктов ТЗ - "пользователю разрешено отдавать свой голос до 11:00 текущего дня (голос отдается один раз в день)"

В таблице votes есть раздельные поля date и time.
Можно ли как-то через constraint или нечто подобное задать ограничение на эти два поля, дабы соблюсти вышеуказанный пункт ТЗ?

В коде приложения задать не проблема; но хотелось бы именно на стороне базы, дабы не производить проверки времени/наличия голоса, а просто обрабатывать Exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не указали диалект *SQL*!  Вот решение для *PostgreSQL*:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "votes" (
  "id" INTEGER
, "date" DATE
, "time" TIME
, CONSTRAINT "check_hour"
    CHECK (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM "time") < 11)
)
;
```

Пример выдаваемой ошибки:

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "votes" violates check constraint "check_hour"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, 2019-01-01, 12:00:00).
```